# how to pass collection of data using an nsarray to a javascript function from Objective C code

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I am trying to render both html and native objective c code together. My purpose is to recognise a html element(suppose a button) and by pressing the button a native(Objective C)alert will get called. And I have succesfully implemented that. Now in I am getting a Json. Now from that Json I want to send two objects back to Javascript using JS Function being called from Objective C. My question is I am unble to call the JS Function if there is any exixtance of special characters(like \,'',etc). And when I remove all the special characters from the String I am able to call the function.

**Here is my code**

```
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<[arr count]; i++)
     {
      image_path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://new.my.anandabazar.com%@",[[arr     objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"imagepath"]];
             str_title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <img src=\"%@\">",[[arr objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"title"], image_path];

       NSString *newVar =[[str_title componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            NSLog(@"%@",newVar);

             [array_data addObject:newVar];

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        NSString *arrayStr = [array_data componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
        NSString *jsFunc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data_abc(['%@'])", arrayStr];

        NSLog(@"now array is %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data_abc(['%@'])", arrayStr]);
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsFunc];
    }
```

**Here is my html code:**

```
 <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="snippetid">



        </ul>
     <script>
          function data_abc(str)
    //      function data_abc()
          {


              var new_str=str;
       document.getElementById('snippetid').innerHTML = str;
                alert(new_str);

          }

     </script>


    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="News">News<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Articles">Articles <br>

    <input type='button' value="Do something in iOS" onclick='window.location="callmycode:cmd=showAlert&var=myVar"'/>


    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Kindly help me out...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSJSONSerialization instead:

```
    NSArray *array_str = @[str_title];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array_str options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data_abc(%@)", jsonString];
    NSLog(@"%@", js);

    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```